# Open particular page of PDF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my application I open a PDF using a web view, and also create a thumbnail of that PDF. I want to open a particular page of my PDF by clicking the thumbnail.

For example, suppose my PDF contains seven pages; then I create seven thumbnails and also open the entire PDF in the web view. If I click the first thumbnail, then in the web view the PDF will be open to the start page, and if I click the fifth thumbnail, then the web view displays the fifth page, and also moves up and down.

So please give me sample code to do that -- I am new to iPhone programming, and I am suffering from one serious problem. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Apple documentation about Drawing with quartz 2d. There's a section just about handling with PDF documents. If you don't like to show a PDF in a UIWebView, you create your own view. Just subclass UIView and overwrite the method -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect for your custom drawing. Create a CGContextRef a draw your PDF directly in that context using the specific function of core graphics. Core Graphics provides a lot of other functions for PDF documents, like Kalle already mentioned.

If you're not really used to core graphics, it's really difficult sometimes and you probably need a lot time to get used to it, so I recommend using UIWebView to display a PDF. It relatively simple.

Comment: thanks for response but i already show my pdf in UIWebView but my question is that i also show thumbnail but now when i click 1'st thumbnail then in UIWebview 1'st page should be open and if suppose 5'th no thumbnail is clicked then in UIWebView contain of 5'th no page of pdf should be open in webview means i want to jump to perticular page of pdf in webview